# AVFoundation or VideoToolbox JPEG compression

Tags: ios, compression, avfoundation, jpeg

I'm trying to capture an image using AVFoundation and save it as JPEG with maximum quality. I'm aware of AVVideoCodecJPEG and AVVideoQualityKey for AVFoundation capture, but it doesn't produce the output I'm looking for. Namely, I need the final JPEG to use the 4:4:4 chroma subsampling. Instead AVFoundation even at quality set to 1.0 (max) produces the image with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling. I tried to capture an image in BGRA32 format and later compress with VideoToolbox - same result. The only way I can get the desired output is by using CGImageDestinationCreateWithData method, but it's too slow - 0.4 sec for 12 MPx image (if I set quality to less than 1.0, the image can be compressed in 0.1 sec for the same size, but than I get again 4:2:0 chroma subsampling).

Did anyone ever succeeded to produce a JPEG with chroma subsampling 4:4:4 using AVFoundation or VideoToolbox? Or maybe there is there any way to accelerate CGImageDestinationCreateWithData method? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there seems to be no support for 4:4:4 chroma sub-sampling using hardware accelerated JPG compression.